# Issue with Firestore and Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I have been several hours trying to understand how to update a Firestore Data Collection, and I almost have done, but there is an issue in the following function. This is part of an Ionic 3, AngularFire2 and Firestore app, I'm trying to upload a photo from the user profile to storage (Firebase) and this part is working fine. But when I try to update the "Photo Url" on the Firestore Data Collection, it  does not do that the first time I call the function, this is done on the second request.

This is the function:

```
saveToDatabase(uploadSnapshot) {
   this.actuser = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
   let userRef = this.afs.collection('usuarios').ref.where('uid', '==', this.actuser);
    userRef.get().then((result) => {
      result.forEach(doc => {
       this.userId = doc.id
      })
    })
    var uid = this.userId;
    var actual = this.afs.collection('usuarios').doc(uid).update({ foto: uploadSnapshot.downloadURL});
    return (uid);     
}
```

The thing that is happening is that the first time I call this function, never enter in the `userRef.get()` part, so I never get `this.userId` updated. And get a Message Error Function:

> CollectonReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type string, but it was undefined

And that is correct because it never enter in the `userRef.get()`. I see on the console and it gets the value after doing the update:

```
var actual = this.afs.collection('usuarios').doc.(uid).update ...
```

Can anybody can tell me what do I need to do to get the this.userId before trying the update of the collection?

Hope somebody understand me, thanks in advance for any comment.